# What is the difference in using Comparable<E> or just E as a parameter in a method?

Tags: java, comparable

I am writing a custom sorted list class that uses a `List<E> orderedList` internally. I am wondering what is the difference between this piece of code:

```
public void add(Comparable<E> e) {
    this.orderedList.add((E) e);
    Collections.sort(OrderedList,null);
}
```

and this one:

```
public void add(E e) {
    this.orderedList.add(e);
    Collections.sort(thisOrderedList,null);
}
```

Comment: We don't know the type of `thisOrderedList`, nor how the `E` type parameter is declared. Please show a short but *complete* example.

Comment: What is the point of having `add(Comparable<E> e)` if you only cast `e` to `E` inside the method?

Comment: OrderedList is basically a new ArrayList<E>();

Comment: I don't know what is the point, that's why I am asking here what is the difference between these two blocks of code. It is not clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: `Collections.sort(someList, null)` is guaranteed to throw a `NullPointerException` no matter what `someList` is.  The second argument to `.sort(...)` is supposed to be a `Comparator` instance.

Comment: You are correct.  The reason for this is that you never defined a `compareTo()` method your ordered list class.

Answer (score 1):

By declaration you can understand the difference.

In first method your expecting `Comparable` type with `E`. Here you can call the methods related to `Comparable`.

In second method your directly expecting `E`. Here `E` is nothing but type `Object` and you can call methods in `Object` only.

About generics From [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html):

> A generic class is defined with the following format:

```
  class name<T1, T2, ..., Tn> { /* ... */ }
```

> The type parameter section, delimited by angle brackets (<>), follows   the class name. It specifies the type parameters (also called type variables) T1, T2, ..., and Tn.
>
> To update the Box class to use generics, you create a generic type declaration by changing the code "public class Box" to "public class Box". This introduces the type variable, T, that can be used anywhere inside the class.
>
> With this change, the Box class becomes:

```
/**
* Generic version of the Box class.
* @param <T> the type of the value being boxed
*/
public class Box<T> {
   // T stands for "Type"
   private T t;

   public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
   public T get() { return t; }
}
```

> As you can see, all occurrences of Object are replaced by T. A type variable can be any non-primitive type you specify: any class type, any interface type, any array type, or even another type variable.
>
> This same technique can be applied to create generic interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The first version of your code

```
public void add(Comparable<E> e) {
    this.orderedList.add((E) e);
    Collections.sort(OrderedList,null);
}
```

requires that `e` be of type `Comparable` and also be descended from type `E`.  If you try to call `add()` in the code above with a type which does not implement `Comparable` it won't even compile.

In the second version of your code,

```
public void add(E e) {
    this.orderedList.add(e);
    Collections.sort(thisOrderedList,null);
}
```

you do not place these restrictions on `e` and it will compile and run without error so long as you pass in an Object of type `E` to the `add()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question. Why in the sort method parameters I need to put null and it doesn't compile without it?

Comment: As @JamesLarge pointed out, if you call `Collections.sort(list, null)` it will throw a `NullPointerException`.  But you could just call `Collections.sort(list)` and it would use the _natural ordering_ of its elements to sort.

Comment: Actually, when I use Collections.sort(list) it doesn't compile at all. It only compiles when I use Collections.sort(list, null).